# AngularJs ui-scroll reload not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ui-utils, ui-scroll

In one of our angular application, we are using [ui-scroll](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-scroll) directive for lazy-loading. I have created a adapter and assigned to the ui-scroll directive. I need to reload the entire data by making API request and refresh data.

From ui-scroll docs, we can see reload() method available for adapter which we are assigning to directive.

```
$scope.listAdapter = {adapter:{remain:true}};
```

We are passing this adapter to custom datasource and which in turn is assigned to the ui-scroll repeater.

When user clicks on a button, i need to reload the entire result by pulling latest results from API. So i tried by adding,

```
$scope.listAdapter.reload();
```

When i tried call reload method, it throws exception stating method not found.
**TypeError: $scope.listAdapter.reload is not a function**

Also i tried by re-assigning datasource and passing empty adapter to the scope variable, but no luck.

If anyone has fixed this, please let me know what need to be done.

Answer (score 0):

Try to define adapter as an empty object:
`$scope.listAdapter = {};`

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer. Otherwise it is a comment.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible kinds of problem I see.

1. **Wrong scope assignment**. It needs to be taken into the account that the `ui-scroll` directive injects the declaratively defined properties into the target scope with the help of AngularJS `$parse` service. It could make the assignment nontrivial. For more details follow [the documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-scroll#assignable-expressions). Here the best practice is to use "Controller As" syntax.
2. **Call too early**. You should not try to execute `Adapter.reload()` (and other Adapter methods) before the `ui-scroll` is initialized, because the `ui-scroll` injects the Adapter object into the target scope during directive's linking proccess which is not immediate. To protect the Adapter methods execution you may use following approach:

   ```
   $scope.doReload = function () {
   if (angular.isFunction($scope.adapter.reload)) {
       $scope.adapter.reload(reloadIndex);
     }
   };
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the same issue. My issue resolved after **two-level object hierarchy.**
Please notice that properties defined via assignable expression could be unavailable. Define at least two-level object hierarchy on your controller:

In HTML

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
  <div ng-if="show">
    <div ui-scroll="item in datasource" adapter="container.adapter">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


In Controller
.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
  $scope.container = { adapter: {} };
}
```